# retrieve id from kendo treeview selected node

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have this scenario.

1) Server Side returns a json encoded array having different fields in it along with primary key i.e., id.
2) A kendo treeview is created from that json
3

I want to do this,

1) User browse the tree and select a node.
2) I want to find the primary id of the tree or any other field that is passed from server side to distinguish the selected node.

I hope I deliver the question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your `select` function as:

```
select    : function (e) {
    // Get clicked node
    var node = e.node;
    // Find it's UID
    var uid = $(node).closest("li").data("uid");
    // Get the item that has this UID
    var item = this.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for find uid you can find it by e.node attribute

```
     select    : function (e) {  
    var uid = e.node.attributes['data-uid'].value;
                var dataItem = this.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
                alert(dataItem.ProductName);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution:

```
onSelect: function(e) {
    var treeView = e.sender,
        dataItem = treeView.dataItem(e.node);
    console.log(dataItem.id);  // retrieves an ID of selected node
}
```